# Как расчитать количество вхождений

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных mySQL

```
id | id_prod | id_shop  | quantity |    date    |
________________________________________________       
 1 |   1     |    1     |      5   | 1450686151 |        
________________________________________________|
 2 |   2     |    1     |      15  |  1420878146|      
________________________________________________|
 3 |   2     |     1    |      15  |  1420878146|
```

мне нужно подсчитать сколько раз были вхождения в колонку id_prod количество раз и умноженое на число стояшее в колонке quantity учитывая что я не знаю какие id будут стоять в id_prod

Comment: А покажите желаемый результат

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее? у вас quantity одинаковый для одинаковых id_prod, тогда group by и всё.

Comment: Вот мне тоже кажется, что всего-то  `select id_prod, sum(quantity) from t group by id_prod`, но может что-то недопонимаю

Comment: @splash58 что бы на выходе я получил
id_prod 2 quantity 30 
id_prod 1 quantity 5 
нукак то так

Comment: @splash58 поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тогда прям так и пишем

```
select id_prod, count(*), sum(quantity) 
    from t 
  group by id_prod
```

результат

```
id_prod count(*)    sum(quantity)
1       1           5
2       2           30
```